# Display hyperlinks to a webpage in each cell as a button in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table in Access 2010 called `Table1`.  Column `NCBI` contains hyperlinks to webpages.  I would like to display each hyperlink as a button in each cell and the caption for that button to be the field value from the same row one column to the left, the column `Gene`.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Does this need to be done on a table or are you willing/able to create a form?

Comment: A form that I could use to filter a large table and display the results would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you must have the table containing the website information.  In my example I have a table called **Websites**.  In the table there is two fields: **`URL`** which contains the direct URL such as *http://google.com* and **`WEBSITE_NAME`** which is simply the name of the website "Google".

Create the form however you would like it to look using whatever `Default View` that you would like, however make sure that the `Record Source` is set to the table containing the website name's and URL's.  In my test one I used `Datasheet`.

On that form make sure at least the **`WEBSITE_NAME`** field is showing on form in a textbox, in mine I called it `txtWEBSITE_NAME`.  There is a property that belongs to the `txtWEBSITE` textbox called `Display as Hyperlink` set that to "Screen Only".

Then go to the events tab of the `txtWEBSITE`, go to the `On Click` event and click the three dots and add this code to the sub procedure:

```vb
Private Sub txtWEBSITE_Click()

    If Nz(Me.URL, "") <> "" Then
        Application.FollowHyperlink Me.URL, , True
    End If

End Sub
```

The `Me.URL` basically just says to use the URL that corresponds to the Website that was clicked. The `Nz()` function basically just checks to make sure that there is actually a URL that belongs to the website that was clicked.

You can add in your own error handling or validation checks but this is the barebones system that you can use to do what you were looking for.